# Set same height as width at a ToggleButton

Tags: android, togglebutton

I have following Layout, with 7 ToggleButtons in a row. Independently from the resolution, I have always 7 Buttons in the complete horizontal width. Now I want to set the same height as the width but it does not work.
I tried following without success ():

```
    tb_Mo = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tB_Mo);

    int btnSize=tb_Mo.getWidth();
    tb_Mo.setHeight(btnSize);
      //and so on for the other Buttons...
```

Second try without success:

```
    int btnSize=tb_Mo.getLayoutParams().width;
    tb_Mo.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(btnSize, btnSize));
         //and so on for the other Buttons...
```

XML:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/tB_Mo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/btntoggle_selector"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textOff="OFF"
    android:textOn="ON" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>  

    <ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/tB_Di"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/btntoggle_selector"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textOff="OFF"
    android:textOn="ON" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>  

        <ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/tB_Mi"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/btntoggle_selector"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textOff="OFF"
    android:textOn="ON" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/> 
          and so on ....
```

What can I do?

[image: Here I want have the same height as the width]

Comment: You should be using `android:layout_width="0dp"` for your `<ToggleButton>`s. Perhaps that will work.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, but its unfortunately not working

Comment: Could you provide the full xml layout?  If the parent is taking up the whole screen and these are the only things in it right now, you would probably be getting this effect.

Comment: Could also be that your `layout_height` is set to `wrap_content`, this may prevent override from your Java function. Try setting it to a specific `dp`.

Comment: Yes it worked!!! I set it to 50dp. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
   <ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/tB_Sa"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btntoggle_selector"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textOff="OFF"
    android:textOn="ON" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

And:

```
    int btnSize=tb_Mo.getWidth();
    tb_Mo.setHeight(btnSize);
```